# Variable doesn't exist in other functions (javascript & Firefox extension)

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla

My Firefox extension must do the following:

1. Save the address of the current page
2. Open a new page
3. Put the address into the content of the new page if a button is pressed

The problem is how to save this address to a variable. If the address is saved in a variable through a function on the first page, the function on the new page, that must show the address when the button is pressed, doesn't have this variable. Should I use a global function or something?

```
function openTab() {
  //Save an address of current page
  path=content.location.href;
  //Open new Tab and select it
  var tab=gBrowser.addTab("chrome://intabeditor/content/editor.html");
  var newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(tab);
  gBrowser.selectedTab=tab;
}

function write() {
  content.body.innerHTML=path;
}
```

The function `openTab()` is executed, when the proper button is pressed. The same with the `write()` function.

Comment: I know, that path isnt global var, but i cant make it global,i think

Answer (score 1):

```
var path = null;
function openTab() {
  //Save an address of current page
  path=content.location.href;
  //Open new Tab and select it
  var tab=gBrowser.addTab("chrome://intabeditor/content/editor.html");
  var newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(tab);
  gBrowser.selectedTab=tab;
}

function write() {
  if (path!=null)
    content.body.innerHTML=path;
}
```

---EDIT
And this example? everything is encapsulated in xopen:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var xopen = function()
    {
        this.path = null;
        this.openTab = function()
        {
            //Save an address of current page
            this.path=content.location.href;
            //Open new Tab and select it
            var tab=gBrowser.addTab("chrome://intabeditor/content/editor.html");
            var newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(tab);
            gBrowser.selectedTab=tab;   
        }

        this.write = function () 
        {
            if (this.path!=null)
                content.body.innerHTML=this.path;
        }
    }
    var wopen = new xopen();

</script>
<button onclick="wopen.openTab()">openTab</button>
<button onclick="wopen.write()">write</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, but i cannot write <pre>var path = null;</pre> outside any function. Functions openTab() and write() are execute, when proper button is pressed.

Comment: ohh, it works too much :( Now when i press openTab button from page that have got "xxx" address, and then press openTab button in "yyy" page, 2 new pages that poped up have got the same this.paht!